# Figuring out complexity of DFS algorithms in 2D matrix

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, depth-first-search, backtracking

In general, I am able to successfully figure out running time complexities of non recursive problems. However, I am not good a figuring out complexities in most recursive problems. Eg ( in Backtracking/ DFS in 2D matrix). I have tried figuring out the complexity of DFS algorithms and I am able to understand how it is O(v+e) , but when it comes to applying dfs  and recursion in 2D matrix problems,I am unable to get the intuition about how to find the complexity of the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I am not copying the code of any specific problem as I want some inputs for how to approach finding time complexities of such problems in general. How, for the sake of discussion, some recent examples where  I bumped into these problems are: 
Given a 2D matrix of characters(in English) and a word,find whether the word exists in the matrix. You are allowed to move in four directions (U,D,R,L).
Another example: Given a string of numbers, find all possible valid Ipv4 IP addresses.

Comment: `Given a 2D matrix of characters(in English) and a word,find whether the word exists in the matrix. You are allowed to move in four directions (U,D,R,L). Another example: Given a string of numbers, find all possible valid Ipv4 IP addresses` :)))

Comment: dfs finds only one answer , you must improve it or in some cases use it in multiple times (note that maybe you see infinite loops) be aware of it